# How can I update a column in SQL Server using RegEx?

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a column in my SQL Server which looks like this:

```
Column
1.1.2 Name1
1.2.3 Name2
1.1 Name3
...
```

So I am trying to remove these numbers in front of the names using an UPDATE statement but so far I couldn't find a correct synthax to do the job.

I was able to do it in python, though, after importing the table in a dataframe. It looks something like this `replace(r'^([0-9]*.[0-9]*.?[0-9]*?)\s\b', "")`.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I replace the column values with an update statement using RegEx?
2. (if the first is not possible) Can I change values from the database by connecting to the database using pyodbc and just use python synthax while modifying the table?

Comment: Although SQL Server does not support regexes,you may be able to get equivalent results (not precisely identical) with `LIKE` patterns and `PATINDEX`, e.g. `SELECT STUFF('1.1.2 Name1', 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9. ]%', '1.1.2 Name1') - 1, '')`. If that's not good enough, then of course you can always change data by streaming rows to the client, determining the update and sending them back again, but this is going to be much, much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your numbers are followed by a space, you can remove everything up to (and including) the first space without using regexes:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ToRemoveNumbers;
CREATE TABLE #ToRemoveNumbers([Column] VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO #ToRemoveNumbers([Column])
VALUES
    ('1.1.2 Name1'),
    ('1.2.3 Name2'),
    ('1.1 Name3'  );


-- remove the numbers:
UPDATE #ToRemoveNumbers
SET [Column] = 
    SUBSTRING
    (
        [Column],
        CHARINDEX(' ', [Column]) + 1,
        2147483647
    )
;
```

2147483647 is max of int, so your string is guaranteed to be less than it.

Answer (score 0):

If the numeric part is always a length of 5 characters & 1 space then Right(Column,len(column)-6) ought to work.

Comment: Nope, the length differs. I edited the OP so it is more clear. Thanks for trying to help, though!